# catching anchor in ul li with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my menu portion of the site.

[image]

this is defined in _Layout.cshtml() page.

when `Neu Gesellschaft` page is loaded, i want to change `css` of the anchor `a`. In order to do so, i have tried following jquery code.

```
    $('ul#menu li a#mnuNG').removeClass();
    $('ul#menu li a#mnuNG').addClass("menuitem-active");
```

But its not working. I think, i have failed to catch the anchor `a`. I have used `F12` in `IE10`. New styles are not implented anyway. Any suggestion would be helpful.

if needed, my `menuitem-active` class :

```
    .menuitem-active
    {
        background:#000000 !important;
        color:#fff !important;
        text-decoration:underline !important;
    }
```

Comment: This should work, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: how would I check if there is any error in console?

Comment: as a side not since you have id of the target element there is no dded to combine it with any other selector so `$('#mnuNG').removeClass().addClass("menuitem-active");` will do

Comment: You can press "F12" to open the console. Here's a working example of your code http://jsfiddle.net/JX4cb/

Comment: i have tried it first. but not working.

Comment: I'm also a beginner to jquery. But why not just use '#mnuNG' to select?

Comment: @Anton: The OP is using IE10, as described above. But `F12` should work there too. Find the logo that says 'Console' and check errors there. You can also try pasting `$('ul#menu li a#mnuNG').addClass("menuitem-active");` in there. If that does what you want you might want to consider wrapping your javascript with `$(function() {});`

Comment: Have you remembered to import the `jquery.js` to your resources?

Comment: Did you wrap the jQuery code in a $(function(){ }); ? It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/htQyS/

Comment: i am using it inside `$(document).ready(function () {})`. And of course. i have added all of my jquery plugins needed. and other jquery  codes are executing fine.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Just making sure. Are you able to execute the code using the chrome console? (you can run it interactively through there)

Comment: no. my work station doesn't allow me to use Chrome :(

Comment: @Anton - No Errors or warning found.

Comment: Your work station? Do you have other limitations perhaps? (also, FF also has a console to run stuff interactively. Can you use that?)

Comment: @AbdurRahim Does this fiddle work for you http://jsfiddle.net/JX4cb/ ? If so then there is something else in your code causing the problem, if not then it's probably something wrong with the version of IE you've got.

Comment: Thanks all for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it happens! but I found the problem and solved it. The problem was the `id` of the `anchor tag a`. It generates a faulty `href` which prevents the page from redirection and many other jquery implementation.

**I just removed `id`  from `<a>` and applied following code. And it worked fine.**

```
    $('#li1 a').removeClass().addClass("menuitem-active");
```

Comment: That's very weird. Good to know it got resolved, but I would dig deeper if I were you to figure out if there are other stuff your IE does which might cause future bugs